# Pull dependencies of modules by referencing parent in maven java project?

Tags: java, module, maven, multi-module

I have a maven-java project (say Project A) with a parent defining modules in its pom.
I also have an external project (say Project B) that requires dependencies of two of the modules from Project A. For now, i have defined the dependency to pull each module individually.
When i replace these two with a dependency on the parent pom, it errors out on build. Is there some modification i need to make to my parent pom of Project A to make this work?

Can this be done in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can this be done in the first place?

Declaring a dependency on an aggregating POM won't get the modules transitively. This is not going to work. It is possible to create a POM to [group dependencies](https://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-pom-best-practice.html#pom-relationships-sect-grouping-deps) though.

For example, EHCache uses this technique. As mentioned in [their documentation](http://ehcache.org/documentation/dependencies.html):

> #### Maven Snippet
>
> To include Ehcache in your project
> use:
>
> ```
>    <dependency>
>        <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
>        <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
>        <version>2.0.1</version>
>        <type>pom</type>
>    </dependency>
> ```

The [`net.sf.ehcache:ehcache`](http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/net/sf/ehcache/ehcache/2.0.1/ehcache-2.0.1.pom) artifact is precisely used to group dependencies (and is distinct from `net.sf.ehcache:ehcache-parent`).

#### References

- The Maven Guide
- [3.6.1. Grouping Dependencies](https://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-pom-best-practice.html#pom-relationships-sect-grouping-deps)

Comment: Great! I will probably go with the grouping the modules in a new pom as deps and referencing that one. Thankyou!